# No muestra variables de entorno de Heroku

Tags: heroku, go, variables-de-configuración

Luego de haber configurado correctamente las variables de entorno desde la linea de comandos, y claramente visibles con

> `heroku config`

Desde main.go, muevo la variable de entorno a una variable y cuando la quiero mostrar, me muestra vacio

```
host := os.Getenv("MYSQL_HOST")
fmt.Println(host)
```

Si voy a Heroku (sitio web), las variables también me las muestra correctamente, pero el tema es que dentro del código de GO no me las interpreta.

Obviamente tengo el `IMPORT "os"`

Que me puede estar faltando ?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Entonces las variables no se muestran cuando corres tu proyecto de forma local, cierto?

Comment: No claro... con un simple fmt.Prinln() no muestra valor, pero si hago 'heroku config' desde la línea de comandos, muestra los valores.

Comment: Ahh, pero cuando corres el proyecto con `heroku local`?

Comment: Nada.. cuando corro el main.go, no me muestra nada, como que al cargar la variable con os.Getenv() no trae nada

Answer (score 0):

### Solución Simple

En linux solo agregas las variables antes de correrlo:

```
$ MYSQL_HOST=localhost go run main.go
```

O bien:

```
$ go build main.go
$ MYSQL_HOST=localhost ./main
```

#### Solución con `heroku local`

El comando `Heroku config` solo acomoda las variables en la app para que sean accesibles a los Dinnos.

Para usarlo de forma local necesitas crear un archivo `.env` que tenga las variables que deseas (en forma llave-valor), por ejemplo:

```
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
KEY=value
ANOTHER_KEY=value2
```

Una vez hecho esto puedes correr el proyecto en la terminal con

```
$ heroku local
```

Lo que hace este comando es buscar el archivo llamado `Procfile`, el cual tiene la instrucción de como correr tu proyecto, para Go es la ruta de tu binario:

```
web: main
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero no me ha funcionado... tengo Windows 10, y aun creando el archivo procfile y corriendo heroku local., veo todos los mensajes de la aplicación, pero no logro que muestre el contenido de la variable de entorno

Comment: host := os.Getenv("MYSQL_HOST")
 user := os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER")
 password := os.Getenv("MYSQL_PWD")
 base := os.Getenv("MYSQL_BASE")

 fmt.Println(host, user, password, base)  esto es lo que no funciona

Comment: Creo que en general no hay problema de usar Windows 10, [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install) esta disponible para ello.
Quizá si usas un ejemplo mínimo como: `package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
    host := os.Getenv("MYSQL_HOST")
    fmt.Println(host)
}` pueda ser útil para jugar y probar.

Comment: Te agradezco pero como dije.. eso no me está funcionando